# why my regex is not working as I expect it

Tags: java, regex

The below code is supposed to find if a given String(line) contains a word of length 2.

```
    String line = "This does not have a two letter word";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\S{2}\\s*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

    System.out.println(matcher.find() ? "YES" : "NO");
```

My reasoning is 
**\s*** - zero or more space before the word
**\S{2}** - non space characters(two)
**\s*** - zero or more space after the word

My program output "YES". It should be "NO".

Comment: The whitespace chars are optional

Comment: In other words, `\s*` does not restrict the pattern and `\S{2}` matches anywhere in the string. Use whitespace boundaries, `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` instead.